# Link to a Lookup record both ways

Tags: visualforce

I have a Object called LPP and it has a lookup to standard Opportunity Object in Salesforce. on a custom VF page for LPP I have a look up for Opportunity which works fine. Below is the code for it`

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        Loan Application
                        <apex:inputField value="{!LPP.Loan_Application__c}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`
```

Now the problem I have is is there a way that on the opportunity record I can have a button saying "Create new LPP" and when a user clicks on it we go to the LPP page and on the LPP page the opportunity gets populated in the lookup field. 
Any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can first try with your own and when you face the problem put your code here.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done by,

1) Creating a complete custom lookup field as described here: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/

2) Enable quick create in your org which won't need any custom VF page to build. Go to Customize--> User Interface--> Check the "Show Quick Create" checkbox as shown below:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: N.B. Quick Create has issues - no Validation Rules are run and hence data integrity can be compromised.  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=basics_creating_records_with_quick_create.htm&language=en